# how to debug the code which is hang

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, freeze

I have a multithreaded code which is hang in some case. I want to know what's the recommended way to debug?

Comment: If you don't give us an idea of what you are doing, we cannot help you

Comment: a truly quality questionn, but it's the title I love most :D

Comment: Perhaps the question is poorly worded (English is evidently not the OP's first language), but I see nothing wrong with asking a general question about how to debug possible deadlocks in C#.

Comment: I just need general guideline here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it hangs, you can attach the debugger and inspect thread state, including callstacks, to your heart's content.  Often there will be one (or more) thread(s) that is (are) in a wait state, and you might be able to work out why that is.

If the state is not self-explanatory at the time of the hang, you can resort to techniques suggested to provide context information for the preceding program flow.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is multi-threaded, you can't debug such as setting breakpoints, trace the statements and pause to see the values of the variables.  The only way in my opinion is to print to the console and see the status from there.

Comment: You can output these trace statements to a file also, but I prefer to see it from the console.